# showing certain legends with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the plto below

how do I:

(1)  remove the sizze legend.

(2) make the color of the bars blue and the legend say "bar legend". Also how to remove the black dot in the bar legend square.

(3) make the color of the points red and the legend say "point legend"

```
dat = data.frame(label = c("A","B","C","D"), group1 = c(1,2,3,5), group2 = c(3,4,5,0), color1 = c("blue","blue","blue","blue") ,
           color12 = c("red","red","red","red"))

dat$sizze = ifelse(dat$group2 ==0 ,0, 2 )

ggplot(dat, aes(x = label, y = group1, fill = color1))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity")  +
 geom_point(data = dat, aes(x = label, y = group2, color =color12, size = sizze), shape=15)+
   guides(
  size = guide_legend(show = FALSE) 
)
```

---> ALso this line:

```
dat$sizze = ifelse(dat$group2 ==0 ,0, 3 )
```

does not seem to work. I can change the 3 to 1 or 5 but the plot still looks the same.  Any idea how to get that to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `guides` and `scale_*_manual`:

```
p1 <- ggplot(dat, aes(x = label, y = group1, fill = color1))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity")  +
  geom_point(data = dat, aes(x = label, y = group2, color = color12, size = sizze), shape=15)

p1 + 
  guides(size = FALSE)+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('blue' = 'blue'),
                    name = 'bar legend')+
  scale_colour_manual(values = c('red' = 'red'),
                      name = 'point legend')
```

[image]

Comment: If you move the fill aesthetic to `geom_bar`, the "black dot" in the bar legend will be removed (e.g. `geom_bar(stat="identity", aes(fill = color1))`

Comment: Thank you. can you see the bottom edit of the question? the size is not changing when I change it.

Comment: You may want to try using the `scale_size` function and play with the `range` argument

Comment: add `scale_size(range = c(3, 6))` to the last line of the plot